# How to share folders on your computer with only one specific android device?

Tags: wi-fi, es-file-explorer, file-sharing

I have marked some folders as shared on the computer to be able to access them on my phone wirelessly using ES File Explorer. That works fine.

However, that makes those folders accessible to every user account on the PC which I don't want to happen. I don't know how to allow only my phone to be able to access the shared folders.

Is there a way?

Comment: You need need a password protection level, that allows a specific account to access the shared files, and you can let only your device access the share, whilst  other accounts won't have access. You may also need to disable administrative shares, if the predominant users are admins as well

Comment: Which OS do you use on your PC?